# npm scripts can't call npm, node, gulp or any globally installed package

Tags: node.js, npm

I seem to have an issue with my NPM installation. I'm on Windows 10, I have npm v6.0.0

Refer to this example package.json files' scripts:

```
"nodev": "node -v",
"npmv": "npm -v"
"gulpv": "gulp -v",
"gulp2v": "./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js -v"
```

Here is the output for running the above:

`npm run nodev` : `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

`npm run npmv` : `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

`npm run gulpv` : `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

`npm run gulp2v` : `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Now, if I run the commands without going through npm:

`node -v` : `v10.0.0`

`npm -v` : `6.0.0`

`gulp -v` : `[22:55:15] CLI version 1.2.1 (\n) [22:55:15] Local version 3.9.1`

`./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js -v` : `[22:55:56] CLI version 3.9.1 (\n) [22:55:56] Local version 3.9.1`

My PATH environment variable is set up correctly, as I'm able to run the commands just fine without going through an NPM script.

I cannot figure out why using an NPM script to run the exact same command is causing issues?

Comment: Did you install your `node.js` globally?

Comment: @DavidR Could you please elaborate on installing it globally? I just used the msi installer for WIndows, from the NodeJS website.. Does that not install it globally?